# Rebuke of Jains - resource after Bodhis approach

Tags: reference-request

Recently Ven. Thanissaro sacrified a lot of effort and time, to make certain Jain-ish approaches via the Buddhas better understandable.

> [The Limits of Description : Not-self](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/uncollected/NotSelfRevisited.html) Revisited. A response to a critique of Ṭhānissaro Bhikkhu’s essay, “[The Not-self Strategy](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/nobleandtrue_en.html#ch7)” (available in the essay collection, Noble & True). (Also available as [pdf format](https://www.dhammatalks.org/Archive/Writings/CrossIndexed/Uncollected/MiscEssays/NotSelfRevisited171126.pdf))

Now, it would be maybe good to read Bhikkhu Bodhis previous critic.

Does any one know if there is a non-commercial shared copy avaliable? And if, maybe possible to be quoted.

Here is a reference to the critique, provided by Nyom Chris, the topic is about:

> These reflections were sparked recently by reading a critique of an article I wrote in 1993, called “The Not-self Strategy.” ... The critique—“**Anattā as Strategy and Ontology**,” written by Ven. Bhikkhu Bodhi—was brought to my attention just over a month ago, even though it has apparently been around for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Using Google I only find it in a book:

- Title -- *Investigating the dhamma : a collection of papers*
- Author -- Bhikkhu Bodhi, edited by Bhikkhu Nyanatusita
- Published -- Kandy, Sri Lanka : Buddhist Publication Society, 2015

Here is a copy of the introduction, taken from [a Google preview of the book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=O0U4DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA25&ots=AvIGYCLYSm&dq=my%20response%20to%20his%20paper%20is%20mized%2C%20part%20agreement%20and%20part%20disagreement&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q=my%20response%20to%20his%20paper%20is%20mized,%20part%20agreement%20and%20part%20disagreement&f=false):

[image]

[image]

So far as I know there's no free/electronic copy of the book.

The summary of [the book on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/168172068X) says,

> This book brings together eight essays of Bhikkhu Bodhi, five of which were earlier published in academic journals and volumes, and three not published before. Most of the essays are critical responses to various modern interpretations of the Dhamma that the author considers to be at odds with the Buddha’s teachings, in particular as transmitted and interpreted by the Theravada school of Buddhism. The other essays are in depth discussions of important Buddhist doctrinal terms.

Comment: Publisher: Pariyatti Publishing (October 15, 2017) . Is this an old essay or has BB changed his view? Anatta is certainly 'ontology'.

Comment: Saddhu for the effort and Zuvorkommenheit, Nyom Chris. It might be left as it is, where it is.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu I think the book's publisher is "Kandy, Sri Lanka : Buddhist Publication Society, 2015". I don't know if the essay is written for the book or old, except for the quote in the OP which says, "was brought to my attention just over a month ago, even though it has apparently been around for some time", which implies that this essay is one of the older ones (i.e. "earlier published in academic journals").

Comment: Thank you, ChrisW for your helpful information! It is because of your post that I was able to find a free PDF Version: <https://www.bps.lk/olib/bp/bp437s_Bodhi_Investigating-Dhamma.pdf>